# RecordSet and Function from vb6 to vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb6, dataset, recordset, vb6-migration

I was wonder how to convert this line of code to vb.net. I changed the dataset to recordset and it is indeed a function. When i convert It gave me this error. The dataset is filled with values from Database Its just that this "!" is the main error can anyone tell me what that means in vb6? The error that came out was"Dataset Cannot Be index because there is no default Properties"

```
             'getting values from database procedure


         If priRecordSet!CodeStatus Then   
   IfCodeStatus = True
Else
    IFCodeStatus = False
End If

Return IfCodeStatus
```

Comment: Use rows(0).Item("ColumnName") to retrive the value

Comment: i place its into a datatable. So its Rows(0)!Codestatus?

Comment: Use:
myTableData.Rows(rowNumber)(columnNumber) 
     or 
myTableData.Rows(rowNumber).Item(columnNumber)

Comment: Place This as an answer so i can accept it (: . @rags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access a particular column value of a particular row, use

```
myTableData.Rows(rowNumber)(columnNumber)
```

or

```
myTableData.Rows(rowNumber).Item(columnNumber)
```